# Removing Click method from Windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting with C# and I went through this tutorial on how to create a simple picture viewer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492135.aspx

You create it with a few buttons, the picture viewing area, and a checkbox.

When I created the form and added some buttons, I was able to run the debugger, see the application, and click on buttons that did nothing.

It seems that to create a method for an event such as a button click you can double-click the button in the form design as a shortcut.

However, I can't seem to remove a method and run it. For example, I created private void pictureBox1_Click. However, I don't need the form to do anything when I click on the picture. I wanted to delete that method. However, I then get an error that states:

"'PictureViewer.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'pictureBox1_Click' and no extension method 'pictureBox1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'PictureViewer.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

What am I missing? Is there something else created besides that one method when I doubleclick the pictureBox? Not that it's particularly bothersome, but it'd be weird to have to leave empty methods in the code for everything you accidentally created.

On a quick second question, where is the code for the controls and containers I add? I would think there'd be a place besides the properties window to set various properties.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the Node for your "Form1" in the Solution Explorer and doubleclick on the Designer.cs (Form1.Designer.cs). I think there is still a reference to the picturebox1 click event. you need to remove this.

Anyway, the Designer.cs holds all information about your controls/containers that you add to your form, but you can still overwrite this by create new values in the regular code behind of 'form1'.

Comment: Thank you. I want to make sure I understand the designer file...so I gather that the class definition of Form1 is split into two files, Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs?

Comment: @allstar No Problem. 'Form1.cs' is the 'Code behind'-File. Here, you can add all your Form1 related selfwritten Stuff. 'Form1.Designer.cs' is an auto-generated file, that is needed to initialize Form1 on startup. These Files together provide Form1 to work.

Comment: @allstar don't forget to check mark an accepted answer for your question. this can help others to identify which 'solution' is acceptable for this type of question. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I didn't mean to waste people's time after the question was already answered.

Answer (score 3):

Your form is spread across two files as a partial class. The background 'wiring up' code is in the myform.designer.cs file and your code is in the myform.cs file. If you just delete the handler from your code the wiring-up code will still exist and you will not be able to compile. So you can go into the designer.cs code and delete the relevant code from there as well but probably not advised if you are just starting out.

The proper thing to do is, in the designer UI, look at the properties of the button (f4) and click the 'events' button across the top bar. You should see your event handler in there somewhere. if you right click in the event handler there is an option to 'reset'. Click that and it will remove the wire up code. If your handler doesn't contain any code then I believe it will also delete that (I haven't got a winfom, project in front of me so cant say for sure).

Comment: Thanks...yeah I removed the appropriate line from the designer file and it worked. I think I see what you're saying about a partial class, I'll keep working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run code and find error string. Open project path in explorel and open your_form.Designer.cs designer in notepad. Find error string in file and remove it(or all piece of code for that element).